# What is the best way to start a function in a ViewMomdel just by clicking on the item in the ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to add the data from my selected item in the ListView to a few entries immediately when clicking on the item.

My XAML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WishListProject.ViewModels"
             x:Class="WishListProject.Views.UpdateGames">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:GameListViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}" ItemSelected="{Binding InsertGame }">
            </ListView>
            <Entry Placeholder="ID" IsVisible="False" Text="{Binding IdEntry}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="GameName" Text="{Binding GameNaamEntry}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="GameGenre" Text="{Binding GameGenreEntry}"></Entry>
            <Entry Placeholder="GameRelease" Text="{Binding GameReleaseEntry}"></Entry>
            <Button Text="Update Game" Command="{Binding UpdateGameCommand}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is the function I want to start for displaying the selected item data in to a few entries USING THE VIEWMODEL:

```
public void InsertGame(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Game game = new Game(); 
            game = SelectedGame;
            IdEntry.Text = game.Id.ToString();
            GameNaamEntry = game.GameNaam;
            GameGenreEntry = game.GameGenre;
            GameReleaseEntry = game.GameRelease;
        }
```

What is the best way to start a function in a VIEWMODEL just by clicking on the item in the ListView?

Comment: I don't think your question name matches your question body.

Comment: Well it's the error I'm getting rn from trying to start a function by just clicking an item in the listview.

Comment: you can only bind to a [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) not a method. but ItemSelected is an event. so you either need to write the handler in code-behind or you need to add a [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?view=netframework-4.8) to your SelectedGame in VM

Comment: You need to use sth like `EventToCommand` helpers in order to keep with MVVM. You can write your own `Behavior` or use an existing one as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand#commands-for-every-element)

Comment: No need to go this far, there is a simple way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your method at the time `SelectedItem` is set. Since you are using bindings, I assume you have something like this in your `ViewModel`:

```
 Game _selectedGame;
 public Game SelectedGame
 {
     get { return _selectedGame; }
     set { 
        SetProperty(ref _selectedGame, value); 

        // code to add in the setter
        if (value != null) 
           InsertGame();
        //----------------------------
     }
 }
```

Just make sure the method is called **after** the property is changed.

Then you will also need to simplify your method signature to:

```
public void InsertGame(){
   ...
}
```

And you should be all set.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

`ItemSelected` is an event and you can't bind it to a method. I will give you a solution about how to start a function in a `ViewMomdel` just by clicking on the item in the `ListView`:

In xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame}" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
```

And in code behind, get the current ViewModel in the `ListView_ItemSelected` method and then call `InsertGame` of ViewModel, you can pass the current `selectedGame` also:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Game selectedGame = e.SelectedItem as Game;
        var currentVm = this.BindingContext as GameListViewModel;
        currentVm.InsertGame(selectedGame);
    }
}
```

And your ViewModel:

```
public class GameListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void InsertGame(Game currentGame)
    {
        GameNaamEntry = currentGame.GameNaam;
    }
    ...
}
```